# How to create an unordered_map with a range of numbers as keys | C++

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map, std

```
int n;
unordered_map<int,int> map(1,n);
```

This gives me error. I want to initialize the map with keys ranging from 1 to n. How can I do that?

Comment: Are the keys supposed to map to any values?

Comment: Not necessarily, but mapping 0 to all the keys in range 1 to n will be fine.

Comment: Note that if you use operator`[]`, any keys that do not exist will be created and [default initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) for you. If the default value, 0 for `int`s, happens to be the value you want, there is no need  to do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to initialize the map with keys ranging from 1 to 5

This would make the keys [1, 5] map to the value 0:

```
std::unordered_map<int,int> map{
    {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}
};
```

If you need many keys, initializing the map with all of them may be too cumbersome and it that case you'll have to use some sort of loop.

Example:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 1000; ++i) map[i] = 0;
```

If you want to hide the fact that a loop of some sort will be used, you can use the constructor of the `unordered_map` that takes iterators and supply a pair of counting iterators. I think you'll find what you need in `boost` or you could write a special iterator for this purpose yourself:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>

template<class T, class U>
struct keygen {
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = std::pair<T,U>;
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using referece = value_type&;
    using difference_type = std::intmax_t;

    keygen& operator++() { ++key; return *this; }
    keygen operator++(int) { auto copy=*this; ++key; return copy; }
    bool operator==(const keygen& rhs) const { return key == rhs.key; }
    bool operator!=(const keygen& rhs) const { return key != rhs.key; }

    std::pair<T,U> operator*() const { return {key, value}; }

    T key;
    U value;
};

int main() {
    // map initialized with keys 1-1000 that maps to 0:
    std::unordered_map<int,int> map(keygen<int,int>{1,0}, keygen<int,int>{1001,0});
}
```

Comment: n=5 was given as an instance. I want to initialize till n numbers, that will be calculated by another operation. Also, if it's a large value like 1000 or something, we can't type it manually.

Comment: @NimishJain Ok, I added an example for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [std::generate_n](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) like this:

```
int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int, int> um;

    std::generate_n(std::inserter(um, std::begin(um)), 5, [i = 1]()mutable{
        return std::make_pair(std::exchange(i, i + 1), 0);
    });

    for(auto& p: um)
        std::cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << '\n';
}
```

*Output:*

```
5: 0
4: 0
3: 0
2: 0
1: 0
```